# html/javascript. Why does my code trigger audio slowly?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

i hope my code trigger the audio when user just press the key on keyboard.
At first time? it's Okay.
but if i frequently pressed some key, the audio was triggered slowly.

This is my html code, loading the audio file.

```
<audio src = "./src/PMLF_Snare_02.wav" id = "audio"></audio>
```

and this is my javascript code which triggers audio file.

```
$(function(){
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

    // Key Down     
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(){
        //padding effect
        $("#"+event.key).css('padding',' 4px 5px 4px 5px');
        
        //play sound
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();       
    });
 
    
    '  
    ' 
    (skip)
    '
    '

});
```

does my code load audio file whenever key is pressed?
how can i get the fast reaction sound like [this site](http://sampulator.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, you can try this code, is vanilla JS but is working, the audio plays when you press Enter keyword (keycode 13). Good luck with your proyect!

```js
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            audio.play();
        };
  });
```